# Compartilhar o conteúdo

Tags: html, whatsapp

Boa tarde, no meu projeto html, coloquei um botão que quando clica ele compartilha no whatsapp com o título que eu colocasse, queria que ele compartilhasse e aparecesse o meu conteudo, mostrando o título, a descrição... igual a globo quando compartilha no whatsapp, aparece o título, a descrição, imagem, no link

Teria como fazer isso?

código:

```
<div class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
   <a data-action='share/whatsapp/share' href='&quot;whatsapp://send?text=&quot; + data:post.title + &quot;-&quot; + data:post.url'>compartilhar</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Que framework é este? É em javascript que esta gerando o HTML?

Comment: No whatsapp para iPhone/iOS não aparece, talvez seja algo proprio do whatsapp para android que detecta o conteudo sózinho

Comment: Ah... esse framework é o bootstrap 3

Comment: Não to falando do HTML, estou perguntando do framework que gera usa esses `data:`. Bootstrap é somente um framework visual, você deve estar usando algum add-on para bootstrap, pois isso ae não é HTML puro.

Comment: Então, peguei de um site, copiei e colei não sei dizer qual é mas era explicando como colocar no wordpress, aqui mesmo no fórum tem explicando como coloca para compartilhar, eu queria que ele compartilhasse a url atual.

Comment: Entendi, mas ainda sim não faz sentido esse `data:post.title`, é um plugin de wordpress? Ou copiou assim de algum lugar aleatoriamente? Fiz uma resposta, veja se ajuda.

Comment: Só para se atenta &quot é = a "

Comment: Nathan atualizei a resposta, acho que lhe falta as meta-tags `og:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao que me parece esses `&quot;` estão errados, eu não sei que framework é este que usou:

```
<a data-action='share/whatsapp/share' href='&quot;whatsapp://send?text=&quot; + data:post.title + &quot;-&quot; + data:post.url'>compartilhar</a>
```

Um link básico deveria ser algo como:

```
 <a href="whatsapp://send?text=Texto%20http%3A%2F%2FMEUSITE/MINHAPASTACAMINHO/">
     Compartilhar no Whatsapp
 </a>
```

> **Note** que o %20 representa o espaço, vou explicar após isso

Se quiser usar aspas (`&quot;`) use após o protocolo (protocolo são os prefixos das urls, por exemplo `file:///`, `http://`, `whatsapp://`), no seu exemplo você adicionou `&quot;` antes de `whatsapp://`, o que não faz muito sentido, a não ser que seja algum framework front-end ou plugin para wordpress.

Os links quando ativados/clicados automaticamente codificam a URL, mas em eventuais situações seria necessário usar coisas como funções de javascript `window.encodeURIcomponent` (vou editar depois e colocar um exemplo), **todavia** é provável que não seja necessário, note que o `&quot;` é necessário somente quando usa `"` (aspas), se for usar apostrofo não é necessário, então faça isso:

> Nota testei ambos exemplos abaixo no iPhone e funcionaram, mostraram customizado, menos a foto miniatura porque o link não tem.

```html
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=&quot;Texto&quot;%20http%3A%2F%2Fpt.stackoverflow.com/a/147442/3635">
    Compartilhar no Whatsapp
</a>
```

Se for usar apostrofo, basta fazer assim:

```html
<a href='whatsapp://send?text="Texto"%20http%3A%2F%2Fpt.stackoverflow.com/a/147442/3635'>
    Compartilhar no Whatsapp
</a>
```

### Como exibir uma prévia do conteudo no WhatsApp:

Para fazer isto é necessário usar o og meta-tags, adicione isto aos headers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Titulo da página</title>

    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Nome do site">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Titulo da página">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Descrição">
    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="http://URL COMPLETA DA IMGEM/photo.jpg">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">

</head>
<body>
```

Se a imagem vier de um servidor HTTPS, por exemplo `https://site/image.jpg`, talvez seja necessário usar `og:image_secure` (documentação http://ogp.me/#structured):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Titulo da página</title>

    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Nome do site">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Titulo da página">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Descrição">
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" itemprop="image" content="https://URL COMPLETA DA IMGEM/photo.jpg">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">

</head>
<body>
```

> Note que é possivel adicionar mais de um `og:image`, mas nem todos "clientes" (como facebook, whatsapp, etc) irão reconhecer mais de uma imagem.

Comment: Amigo consegui fazer aqui, obrigado pela sua atenção